# Why require $R$ to be a field to obtain that $R[\alpha]/(2\alpha^2)$ is either an exterior algebra or a polynomial algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

The following is on page 227 of Hatcher's algebraic topology:

> Polynomial algebras are examples of free graded commutative algebras, where ‘free’ means loosely ‘having no unnecessary relations.’ In general, a free graded commutative algebra is a tensor product of single-generator free graded commutative algebras. The latter are either polynomial algebras $R[α]$ on even-dimension generators $α$ or quotients $R[α]/(2α^2)$ with $α$ odd-dimensional. Note that **if $R$ is a field then $R[α]/(2α^2)$ is either the exterior algebra $Λ_R[α]$ if the characteristic of $R$ is not 2, or the polynomial algebra $R[α]$ otherwise**. Every graded commutative algebra is a quotient of a free one, clearly.

My question is:

Why do we need $R$ to be a field to get the statement in bold?
I understand that when $\alpha$ is odd-dimensional then either $\alpha^2=0$ giving $R[α]/(2α^2)=Λ_R[α]$, or $2=0$ leading to $R[α]/(2α^2)=R[α]$. Where should I use the 'being a field' condition?

According to the definition of exterior/polynomial algebra in this book, it only requires $R$ to be a (commutative, unital) ring.

Comment: It's late for me but I think that you need 2 to be invertible in $R$ for the first statement, and for the second (in char 2) you're just modding out by the zero ideal. Maybe try to prove that $R[\alpha]/(2\alpha^2)=\Lambda_R[\alpha]$ explicitly (write down a map $R[\alpha] \to \Lambda_R[\alpha]$ with kernel $2\alpha^2$)

Answer (score 1):

The graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(2\alpha^2)$ with $\alpha$ in degree 1 has $2\alpha^2 =0$ but $\alpha^2 \neq 0$. As Andres Mejia points out, you can only deduce that $2 \alpha^2=0 \Longrightarrow \alpha^2=0$ if 2 is invertible in the ring $R$.

By the way, this graded ring has $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees 0 and 1, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in degree 2.